# what is the series expansion(summation) of $( 1- x)^{-3}$?

Tags: sequences-and-series

what is the  series  expansion of $( 1- x)^{-3}$ ?

My attempt : I know  $(1-x)^{-1} = \sum_{n=0}^{ \infty} x^n$

$(1-x)^{-2} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (n+1) x^n$

But here Im confuse  about $( 1- x)^{-3}$ ?

Comment: Do you know how the expansion of $(1-x)^{-2}$ is derived? Because you can do the same thing (with one tiny extra step) to get the one that you want.

Comment: An alternative to differentiation is to multiply the two known series.

Comment: oks thanks  u sir @BrianM.Scott

Comment: Okss  thanks u @RobPratt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that
\begin{align}
\dfrac{d}{dx}\left(\dfrac{1}{1-x} \right)&= \dfrac{1}{(1-x)^2},
\end{align}
and hence
\begin{align}
\dfrac{d^2}{dx^2} \left(\dfrac{1}{1-x} \right) &= \dfrac{d}{dx}\left(\dfrac{1}{(1-x)^2} \right) = \dfrac{2}{(1-x)^3}.
\end{align}
So, by rearranging,
\begin{align}
\dfrac{1}{(1-x)^3} &= \dfrac{1}{2} \dfrac{d^2}{dx^2} \left( \dfrac{1}{1-x} \right) \\
&= \dfrac{1}{2} \dfrac{d^2}{dx^2} \left( \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}x^n \right),
\end{align}
where the final step of course assumes $|x|<1$. I leave it to you to continue.

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

The [Generalized Binomial Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem#Newton's_generalized_binomial_theorem) says that

$$(1+x)^\alpha = \sum_{k \geq 0} \binom{\alpha}{k} x^k$$

---

I hope this helps ^_^